# Can I exchange sum and $\partial/\partial x$ with local uniform convergence in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $S_n(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x,y)$ be the sum of functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that $S_n(x,y)$ converges uniformly to $S(x,y)$ in any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (More precisely, in $\mathbb{H}$, but it is not important.)

Then is it possible to exchange the sum and partial derivative? Namely,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} S(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f_k(x,y)
$$

? What about if we add the condition that $S(x,y)$ is absolutely convergent?

I doubt that this would be false, since if we fix $y$, then the right-hand-side is $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n'(x)$ and the left-hand-side is $S'(x)$, so we must show that

$$
S'(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n'(x).
$$

Baby rudin say that to do this, we need that $S_n'(x)$ converges uniformly, but here we have only that $S_n(x)$ converges uniformly.

But there is a possibility that there is something I do not know. Indeed, in the paper, 'Jeon, Daeyeol; Kang, Soon-Yi; Kim, Chang Heon
Weak Maass-Poincaré series and weight 3/2 mock modular forms.', (this is the motivation of this question),  in p.5 (the arxiv ver), below the equation (3.3), the author exchange the sum and the laplacian operator which consist of the partial derivatives, and the summation has only the conditions that uniformly converges and absolutely on compacta.

So if you know any other theorem about this, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample we can just look at functions of $x$ alone. Define

$$S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}-\frac{\sin((n+1)^2x)}{(n+1)^2}\right).$$

The sum on the right is telescoping and converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathbb R$ to $\sin x.$ But $S'(x) = \cos x,$ and the sum of derivatives on the right is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( \cos(n^2x)-\cos((n+1)^2x).$$

That doesn't look very convergent to me. In particular, if $x=\pi,$ the terms of this series oscillate from $-2$ to $2.$

Comment: Thank you! Then how the author exchange the sum and derivatives in the paper? Hmm...I will send them an e-mail.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide some context on the paper. Sometimes uniform convergence of $\sum f_n$ does imply uniform convergence of $\sum f_n'$ as in the theory of analytic functions in $\mathbb C.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First of all $y$ has no role to play in this question. To give a counter-example make your functions independent of $y$.

Now think completely in terms of $S_n$ forgetting (for the moment) about $f_k$'s. You are asking if $S_n \to S$ uniformly on compact sets implies that $S_n' \to S'$. There are many counter-examples for this and it is easy to find one in which $\sum f_k$ also converges absolutely.